# Drupal 10 views: fields/custom text show translated label for field

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-9

I am building a bilingual site with Drupal 10 and I am using views to show content items listings. In my views I am using field: Custom text to format the teasers of each item the way I want.

I have translated all the fields of my content types and my issue is how to show in the custom text each field's label.

Here is how my view's configuration looks like:
[image]

Here is an example of such a custom text:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 teaser-wrapper">
    <div class="teaser-image">{{ field_image }}</div>
    <div class="teaser-header">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="teaser-text">{{ body }}</div>
    <div class="row teaser-field">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 teaser-field">
                <span class="lbl">Location: </span>
                <span class="val">{{ field_region }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 teaser-field">
                <span class="lbl">Path Length: </span>
                <span class="val">{{ field_path_length }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 teaser-field">
                <span class="lbl">Activities: </span>
                <span class="val">{{ field_nature_activities }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see at the moment I am just using hardcoded values for the labels.

How can I print their translated values?

Comment: Seeing you're getting no response and put a bounty out, you could also try to ask the question on [drupal exchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) as well

Answer (score -1):

Add the twig translation filter to your custom labels. For example:

```
<span class="lbl">Location: </span>
```

becomes:

```
<span class="lbl">{{ 'Location: '|t }}</span>
```

Then, go to Configuration, Regional and Language, User Interface Translation (/admin/config/regional/translate) and search for 'Location:'. You can then enter the translation for the other language.

Any custom text you need translated can have the |t filter added (as long as it's a Twig template or accepts Twig syntax) and it will then appear in the User Interface Translation list for you to provide it's translation.